# Google sketchup objects transparent in opengl?

Tags: opengl, transparency, lwjgl, sketchup

I have made two objects in googlesketchup.
[link1](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/685/opengll.png/)
.On the link you can see a picture of the model. I just made two rectangles and then used push and pull, later I used paint bucket to paint the textures on.

I export this file as .obj and then imported in opengl. The weird thing is that you can see one object through the other object. There is a picture.
[link2](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/18/sketchvb.png/)

Any ideas how to make the objects non-transparent?

Comment: Import in OpenGL? What do you mean by that? How do you render the objects? Show us the specific code and we might be able to help you along. You're probably using some transparency somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me a depth test problem.

You can notice it by rotating the model view matrix and you will notice that the transparency will follow an odd behavior.

Try to enable the DEPTH test in your code by adding the following code line:

Using C:

```
glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Cheers

Comment: It is true I didnt enable depth test and I rotate the model view matrix. But when I enable GL_DEPTH_TEST. The whole screen just goes black.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to enable depth testing? (`glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`)